# gets is not working in c

Tags: c, gets

In the Bellow C program, `gets` is not working so I have used `scanf` to get the student name from the standard input.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct student
{
    char name[10];
    int roll, sub[6], total, age;
};

int take(int n, struct student s[])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        s[i].total=0;
        printf("\n\nEnter the name of the %d student :",i+1);
        gets(s[i].name);//over here gets is not working
        //scanf("%s",s[i].name);
        printf("Roll no :");
        scanf("%d",&s[i].roll);
        printf("Enter your Age : ");
        scanf("%d",&s[i].age);
        for(j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter the Marks of Subject %d : ",j+1);
            scanf("%d",&s[i].sub[j]);
            s[i].total=s[i].total+s[i].sub[j];
        }
    }
}

main()
{
    int n;
    struct student s[10];
    printf("Enter how Student Details you want to Enter : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    take(n, s);
}
```

How can I use `gets`?

Comment: You shouldn't use `gets` anyway. It has security problems. Why do you want to?

Comment: "gets is not working in c" is a tautology.

Comment: [DO NOT use `gets()`, it is dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917). use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Comment: `main()`....please update your book/tutorial.

Comment: "is not working" is not a problem description. What behaviour do you observe? What do you expect? Precise questions can be answered.

Comment: There is no `gets` in C(11).

Answer (score 1):

Mixing `scanf` with `gets` or `fgets` can be problematic regarding newline handling.

Prior to your call to `gets`, you call `scanf` with a format string of `"%d"`.  This goes over any leading whitespace, then (loosely speaking) reads in a sequence of digits and stops at the first non-digit.  When this call is done, there is a newline left in the input buffer (as well as any non-digits you may have entered after your digits).

When you then call `gets`, it reads up to and including the next newline, which the newline being discarded.  This results in an empty string being read into `s[i].name`.

Before calling `gets`, you need to flush everything in the input buffer up to and including the next newline.  You can do that with a `getchar` loop as follows:

```
int c;
while ((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Also, you shouldn't use `gets` as it has no means to prevent overrunning your input buffer which could lead to undefined behavior.  You should use `fgets` instead:

```
fgets(&s[i].name, sizeof(s[i].name);
if (strrchr(s[i].name, '\n') != NULL) {
    *strrchr(s[i].name, '\n') = 0;
}
```

The `fgets` function will include the newline in the read string if there is room, so the following statements will remove the newline if it exists.

Comment: the `getchar()` loop is perfectly fine but can't the same be done with some fancy `scanf` pattern?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I don't think there's a pattern that can do this.  `scanf` patterns can be tricky to work with anyway, so better to use something more straightforward.

Comment: I was thinking something like `scanf("%*s");`, but yes, a for loop with check on `'\n'` and `EOF` is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out some mistakes that might be causing the problem.

First define a **return type of main function** (generally `int main()`).

Declare the array of **structure variable globally**, because it might be restricted to access the elements of structure with `gets` since gets faces security problems (don't know much about it).

You must not use `gets`, instead you can do this by using `scanf` only. It stops taking input when first white space occurs when used in layman format.

Use `scanf` in this way to make it accept whitespaces :

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",s[i].name);
```